# Postgresql joining one column with 2 not null columns

Tags: postgresql

I have 2 tables that I want match by ID.

EDIT: Table1:

```
    | id  | other columns A |
    | 23  |   ...           |
    | 27  |   ...           |
    | 9   |   ...           | 
    | 50  |   ...           |
```

Table2:

```
| id_new  | id_old | other columns B
| 23      |   7    | ...
| 27      |   8    | ...
| 33      |   9    | ...
```

Problem is that the second table contains 2 ID columns: first with new ID second with the old one - both can match the ID from first table.

EDIT: there are some rows from table A which ID not match neither id_new nor id_old. But I want them to retain in the new table.

This is my desired result:

```
     | id  | id_new | id_old | other columns A + B
     | 23  |  23    |   7    |  A + B
     | 27  |  27    |   8    |  A + B
     | 9   |  33    |   9    |  A + B 
     | 50  |  --    |   --   |  A
```

I tried this one but it's a huge dataset and my query takes a long time to execute.

```
create table spoj2 
as 
    select * 
    from table1 
    left join table2   on table1.id = table2.id_new 
                       or table1.id = table2.id_old
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you need?

```
select table1.id, IFNULL(T2A.id_new, T2B.id_new) as id_new
, IFNULL(T2A.id_old, T2B.id_old) as id_old
FROM table1 
LEFT JOIN table2 as T2A ON table1.id = T2A.id_new 
LEFT JOIN table2 as T2B ON table1.id = T2B.id_old
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH t1(id,o_t1) AS ( VALUES
  (23,'...'),
  (27,'...'),
  (9,'...')
), t2(id_new,id_old,o_t2) AS ( VALUES
  (23,7,'...'),
  (27,8,'...'),
  (33,9,'...')
)
SELECT t1.id,t2.id_new,t2.id_old,t1.o_t1,t2.o_t2 FROM t1
  INNER JOIN t2 ON t2.id_new = t1.id
UNION ALL
SELECT t1.id,t2.id_new,t2.id_old,t1.o_t1,t2.o_t2 FROM t1
  INNER JOIN t2 ON t2.id_old = t1.id;
```

Result:

```
 id | id_new | id_old | o_t1 | o_t2 
----+--------+--------+------+------
 23 |     23 |      7 | ...  | ...
 27 |     27 |      8 | ...  | ...
  9 |     33 |      9 | ...  | ...
(3 rows)
```

Comment: Sorry I did not mention that there are some rows from table A with ID that not match neither id_new nor id_old. But I want them to retain in the new table.